# need consulting for a gui with 5 settings to be chosen by the user

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu

I would like to let the user set 5 different settings. Each setting has a finite amount of values to choose (in my case : smaller, small, normal, large, very large)

I tried to use the UIPickerviews for this, but it needs a lot of space and I would like to have all on one page. I realized, that apple doesn't support simple dropdowns in IOS!?!?

following sample just shows only one setting and it fills up 1/3 of the screen.

[image]

In Android I managed to do this with simple dropdowns.

Any hints on how I could do this, without programming my own dropdown box ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not have dropdowns as you say. I have created a custom control for my company that implements a dropdown. Some of my fellow iOS developers have yelled at me and said the dropdowns don't follow Apple's HIG. (You can take a look at our free app [**FaceDancer**](http://tinyurl.com/facedancer) to see our dropdown control if you're interested.)

Apple uses picker views instead. What you can do is to have some sort of clickable element for each item (buttons for each one, e.g. "pick size", or make each field itself clickable) that displays a picker on top of the screen to let the user pick that value.

Note that there are large numbers of (both free and paid) third party frameworks offering all kinds of additional controls. I bet somebody has implemented a drop-in dropdown menu for iOS. Take a look at [**CocoaControls**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) and search the iOS section for "dropdown". You can also look on Github and SourceForge.net.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Regarding the solution to popup the picker. Will this be a UIPickerview, which I would show after pressing the "pick size" button and hide after changing the value in the UIPickerview ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a UISegmentedControl.
In my case with only 5 values, for me its the best choise. But for more then 10 values we have to use obviously external controls as Duncan mentoined.

```
var arraySizes5 = [sverysmall, ssmall, snormal, slarge, sverylarge];    
var segmentcontrol_TextSizeTextViewer = UISegmentedControl();
segmentcontrol_TextSizeTextViewer = UISegmentedControl(items: arraySizes5);
self.view.addSubview(segmentcontrol_TextSizeTextViewer);
```